# Publishing my 1st app -> premission denied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've created my 1st c# MVC3 EntityFramework app and moved in into the IIS folder... after running it locally it goes

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

The problem is that I've already created SQL account in MS SQL Management Studio and my connection string has the login and passwork inputed like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;user id=kwestionariusz;password=PASSWORD;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, I've added the same into this, I dunno if it's necessary though:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; user id=kwestionariusz; password=PASSWORD; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check that kwestionariusz has CREATE permissions

Comment: And does the `kwestionariusz` user have the privileges to create a new database? I'd say - nope. If it's `code-first` approach, allow the user to do everything with the DB, if it's `database-first`, well, you already have the database, there shouldn't be a creation process. I gotta say though, my Entity Framework connection string looks a little bit different... But I'm no expert on connection strings :)

Comment: Have you added permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE account?

Comment: I believe (altrough I'm database noob) I've granted this user every premission I could (just to be sure for now)... after logging in via SQL Management Studio as "kwestionariusz" I can create a database. What else can be wrong?

Comment: @Josh - I see no such account but I just added permissions for "NT SERVICE\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS". Is that it? ;/

Comment: May we see the query? If you can log in with the user and create a database on MS, then it has permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using code first, then make sure that the user has the permission to create the database.

```
class BlogContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<BlogEntry> BlogEntires
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

The name of the connection must match the classname of the db context:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="BlogContext"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=(local);Database=ef4;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If your database is already there, modify the constructor of your DbContext:

```
    class BlogContext : DbContext
    {

        public BlogContext()
        {
           System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
             new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BlogContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<BlogEntry> BlogEntires
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Invalid object name 'dbo.Customers'".

So we sure are closer to the solution as the error has changed - thanks for that!

Any ideas next? :)

Comment: Is the database already created correctly with all the needed tables? There can be different databases on one server with different schemas. Do you really want to create the tables in the master database? Can you create a table in management studio with the specified user?

Comment: I don't know much what I'm doing right now, I just want it to work just as it worked during debugging on my home PC... I wanted EntityFramework to create the database itself but then I just created it for him (with all the tables) and added "initial catalog" but the error is still the same; even since I have "dbo.Customers" table in the database...

Comment: Try fully qualifying the object. Maybe the default database is different. Like Master.dbo.Customers.

Comment: In the connectionstring example above, you are accessing a database in that mode: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;user id=kwestionariusz;password=PASSWORD;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true. This is very local to your webapplication. Try something like Server=(local);Database=yourdatabasename;Trusted_Connection=true;  This way you can attach the sql profiler and you will find your bug.

Comment: You have to install sql server (express: you can't profile) on the webserver too, not just visual studio.